# Dated Between 2 date variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, datediff

I have a table with Customers IDs,Name Room Number,Start Date and End date. I want to create a list of dates (daily breakdown) between the start date and end date but want it to look like the tbale i have mocked up in excel in the link below:

[image]

i have used

`=IF(TEXT(D2,"DD/MM/YYYY")=TEXT(E2,"DD/MM/YYYY"),"Same",IF(F2=DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),DAY(D2)),"Start",IF(F2=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2),DAY(E2)),"End","Between")))` formula in the Logic ColumN

I have tried to intregrate the following bit of SQL into my query but cant seem to get it to do what i want:

```
declare @fromdate dateTIME
set @fromdate= '1/1/2017'(Wanted to used Column Startdate)
declare @todate dateTIME = getdate()-1(Wanted used Column Enddate)
;with CTE AS
(SELECT @fromdate AS RESULT
UNION ALL
SELECT RESULT + 1 FROM CTE WHERE RESULT<=@todate
)
SELECT Result,1 as Count FROM CTE OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Images are not helpful to anyone when asking questions about data. Post your data in a **consumable** format. This'll be a good start for you: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Question is not clear to me

Comment: Hi @paparazzo my desired result would be to Select [ID],[Name],[Room],[StartDate],[EndDate] & then set fromdate as [Startdate] & set todate as [EndDate] and use the SQL above to produce the date inclusive column and use a formula similar to one one i used in excel to produce a table like my mock table in the picture

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what isn't working in your query. If it entails getting the rows per day, the easiest way to go about this is to actually have a date-table ready in your database. You can refer to this date-table in your view. See below an example which I have used in multiple projects.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillDateTable](@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE) AS
BEGIN 
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DateTable;

WITH CTERecursive AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS 'CalendarDate' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,CalendarDate) AS 'CalendarDate' 
    FROM CTERecursive 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,CalendarDate)<=@EndDate
), TotalCalendar AS (
SELECT CalendarDate
    , DAY(CalendarDate) AS 'Day'
    , MONTH(CalendarDate) AS 'Month'
    , YEAR(CalendarDate) AS 'Year' 
    , DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CalendarDate)+1,CalendarDate) AS 'FirstDayOfWeek' 
    , DATEADD(DAY,6,DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CalendarDate)+1,CalendarDate)) AS 'LastDayOfWeek' 
FROM CTERecursive
)
INSERT INTO dbo.DateTable ([CalendarDate], [Day], [Month], [Year], [FirstDayOfWeek], [LastDayOfWeek], [NewWeek])
SELECT  *
    ,   NewWeek=CASE WHEN CalendarDate=FirstDayOfWeek THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM    TotalCalendar 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
END
```

Furthermore, it'd be wise to use DATEADD instead of +1 in your CTE.

```
DECLARE @fromdate DATE
SET     @fromdate=CONVERT(DATE,'20170101',112)
DECLARE @todate DATE=GETDATE()-1
;
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT @fromdate AS RESULT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,RESULT) FROM CTE WHERE RESULT<=@todate
    )
SELECT [DateInclusive]=RESULT
,1 as Count FROM CTE OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

UPDATE: I'll presume  you have a table with the Id, Room, Name, Start- and Enddate readily available. Your query could be structured as follows, yielding an overview similar to your Excel mockup:

```
DECLARE @Bookings TABLE ([Id] VARCHAR(30), [Room] INT, [Name] VARCHAR(255), [Startdate] DATE, [Enddate] DATE)
INSERT INTO @Bookings VALUES ('V123789',8,'H. Brown','20170201','20170315'),('V555589',1,'J. Frost','20170205','20170420');

WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT Id, [Startdate] AS InclusiveDate FROM @Bookings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, DATEADD(DAY,1,InclusiveDate) FROM CTE WHERE InclusiveDate < (SELECT Enddate FROM @Bookings WHERE Id=CTE.Id)
    )
SELECT B.[Id], B.[Room], B.[Name], B.[Startdate], B.[Enddate], CTE.[InclusiveDate]
, CASE WHEN CTE.[InclusiveDate]=B.[Startdate] THEN 'Start' 
       WHEN CTE.[InclusiveDate]=B.[Enddate] THEN 'End' 
       WHEN CTE.[InclusiveDate]>B.[Startdate] AND CTE.[InclusiveDate]<B.[Enddate] THEN 'Between' END AS Logic 
FROM CTE 
JOIN @Bookings B on B.Id=CTE.[Id]
ORDER BY B.[Id], CTE.[InclusiveDate] ASC
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Erik-Bart Rosman that helpful but my desired result would be to Select [ID],[Name],[Room],[StartDate],[EndDate] & then set fromdate as [Startdate] & set todate as [EndDate] and use the SQL above to produce the date inclusive column and use a formula similar to one one i used in excel to produce a table like my mock table in the picture.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.